# Getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error with Node.Js server serving Video & Audio file

Tags: rest, video, mern, nginx-reverse-proxy, connection-refused

> ### Getting issue when I'm using other device to access the *video* and *audio* file alike image file and json and other text file.

#### I am using Angular as frontend and Express as backend and I have hosted it in my local system using Nginx.

#### It is working perfectly fine when I'm using http://localhost/api/media/audio/audio.mp3 to get the file from the backend.

[audio is playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9JVs.png)

#### It is not working when I using http://192.168.0.100/api/media/audio/audio.mp3

[audio file is not playing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zANcU.png)

#### Images are working fine on both http://192.168.0.100/api/media/image/hulk.jpg (my computer's lan ip) and http://127.0.0.1/api/media/image/hulk.jpghttp://192.168.0.100/api/media/image/hulk.jpg

[image working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc1QG.jpg)

#### And Other files also working

[Text file working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpVxj.png)

#### The frontend working over 192.168.0.100 (over LAN) but Youtube embed not working

[frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfYjL.png)

> Nginx -> /etc/nginx/sites-available      *default* file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;



    root /var/www/html;


    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location /api {
        # proxy pass for the backend server
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        }
```

> ## **Please someone do help me with this problem**